# how can you check if a void function ran successfully with printf?

Tags: c

A friend told me there is a way to check with `printf` **without** modifying the original `void` function.

But I can't see how you can do it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void test()
{
  int a = 1;
  int b = a;
}

main()
{
    printf("%d",test());    
}
```

I kept getting

> error: invalid use of void expression

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Are you using C++ or C? If your using C++ then you shouldn't be using printf. Use std::cout.

Comment: You can't just throw the function call into the printf. You have to define your success condition, check it in the function, and printf appropriately. Programming != magic.

Comment: @Caesar sorry i meant C.

Comment: @Dan I understand what you mean and that's what I thought too. So it looks like my friend is BS with me...

Comment: What does "ran successfully" mean? Is there any other way it could run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see from your edit that you want to do this without modifying the function. You can employ the comma operator to make the function call in a `printf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = a;
}

main()
{
    printf("%d\n", (test(), 0));

    // or even this, to be more explicit:
    printf("%s\n", (test(), "test() was called."));
}
```

The comma operator evaluates the first operand - in this case your function call - and discards the result, then evaluates the second operand and the result is the result of the entire expression.

Comment: there is definitely no any other magical way to check it without change the void function itself?

Answer (score 0):

An example would be to pass memory pointer into the void function and fill it with data you need to see if your void function worked.

```
void
test_funtion(bool *answer)
{
    answer = false;
    // do stuff
    if(error happens)
        return;
    answer = true;
    return;
}
```

I don't see how you would use printf to let the program know.
Only way you would use printf for visual logging for yourself, but not the machine.